# How can I verify that two classes are assigned to the same city? Follow-up issues

Tags: c#, ienumerable, multiple-inheritance, assign, object-class

There are three classes with interfaces Train: ITrain, Line: Iline and City: ICity. Generally, I advanced in the code and resolved TEST 3 & 4 but caused new issues.

I have following issues: 
1. Test 1 on line 19 : "Sequence contains no elements" 
2. Test 2 on line 38 : "Sequence contains no elements" 
3. Test 5 on line 90 : "Expected value to be 2, but found 0"

My guess I am missing an increasing increment of Assignment and correct assigning in between Assignment & Train & Line. However, I do not have a clue how to solve the issue.

```
internal class Line : ILine
{
    private List<Station> _stations;

    internal IEnumerable<Train> _trains;

    internal Line(string name, City city)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.City = city;
        _stations = new List<Station>();
        _trains = new List<Train>();

    }
    public string Name
    {
        get;
    }

    public ICity City
    {
        get;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IStation> Stations
    {
        get
        {

            return _stations;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ITrain> Trains
    {
        get
        {
            return _trains;
        }
    }
 }
```

---

```
internal class Train : ITrain
{
    private List<Line> _lines;
    internal Train(string name, Company company)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Company = company;
        _lines = new List<Line>();
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get;
    }
    public ICompany Company
    {
        get;
    }
    public ILine Assignment
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public void AssignTo(ILine l)
    {
        if (!(Assignment == null || l == null || Assignment.City == l.City))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        Assignment = l;
        foreach (var line in _lines)
        {
            //verify that LINE is not null
            if (Assignment != null && Assignment.Trains.Contains(this))
            {
                //need to remove this from l1.trains
                ((List<Train>)Assignment.Trains).Remove(this);
                ((List<Train>)l.Trains).Add(this);
            }
            if (Assignment == null && Assignment.Trains.Contains(this))
            {
                //need to remove this from l1.trains
                ((List<Train>)l.Trains).Remove(this);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
//TESTs are not passing on line 19, 38, 46
// Only test T3 and T4 function
[Test]
public void T1_trains_can_be_assigned_to_a_line()
{
  ICity s = CityFactory.CreateCity("Paris");
  ICompany c = s.AddCompany("SNCF");
  ITrain t1 = c.AddTrain("RER1");
  ITrain t2 = c.AddTrain("RER2");
  t1.Assignment.Should().BeNull();
  t2.Assignment.Should().BeNull();
  ILine l = s.AddLine("RER A");
  t1.AssignTo(l);
  t1.Assignment.Should().BeSameAs(l);
  t2.Assignment.Should().BeNull();

  //Error:Sequence contains no elements
  l.Trains.Single().Should().BeSameAs(t1);
}
[Test]
public void T2_when_a_train_is_assigned_to_a_line_he_losts_its_previous_line()
{
  ICity s = CityFactory.CreateCity("Paris");
  ICompany c = s.AddCompany("SNCF");
  ILine l1 = s.AddLine("RER A");
  ILine l2 = s.AddLine("RER B");
  ITrain t1 = c.AddTrain("RER1");
  t1.AssignTo(l1);
  t1.Assignment.Should().BeSameAs(l1);
  t1.AssignTo(l2);
  t1.Assignment.Should().BeSameAs(l2);
  l1.Trains.Count().Should().Be(0);
  //Error:Sequence contains no elements
  l2.Trains.Single().Should().BeSameAs(t1);
}
[Test]
public void T5_line_can_have_mutiple_trains()
{
  ICity s1 = CityFactory.CreateCity("Paris");
  ICompany c1 = s1.AddCompany("SNCF");
  ILine l1 = s1.AddLine("RER A");
  ITrain t1 = c1.AddTrain("RER1");
  ITrain t2 = c1.AddTrain("RER2");
  t1.AssignTo(l1);
  t2.AssignTo(l1);
  //Error: Expected value to be 2, but found 0 
  l1.Trains.Count().Should().Be(2);
  l1.Trains.Should().Contain(t1);
  l1.Trains.Should().Contain(t2);
  t1.AssignTo(null);
  l1.Trains.Single().Should().BeSameAs(t2);
}
```

---

```
void AssignTo(ILine l);
```

The third Test is checking that trains and lines belongs to the same city.

Comment: So what is the problem? Does one of the tests fail? Note that you can [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: All of the folow-up tests (starting from test 3) are failing as I am not capable to verify if trains and lines belongs to a same city. I need to pass city to he method AssignTo.

Comment: What do you mean by "train belongs to a city"? There is no reference to a City in the Train class.

Comment: Train belongs to a specific line and then I should verify that train and line are assigned to a same city. I don't know how to proceed here.

Comment: As the relation of Train to City is always via Train -> Line -> City, how can this ever fail? Or is it meant that whenever a Train is assiged to Line1 and then the assignment changes to Line2, Line2 must be in the same City as Line1?

Comment: It is failling because of no exception was thrown for  "action2.ShouldThrow<ArgumentException>();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the following is meant: whenever a Train is assiged to Line1 and then the assignment changes to Line2, Line2 must be in the same City as Line1.

This could be catched by something like:

```
if (!(Assignment.City == l.City))  throw new ArgumentException(...);
```

As it seems that null values are also allowed, a more complete check would be

```
if (!(Assignment == null || l == null || Assignment.City == l.City)) throw...
```

Note that this would allow to teleport a train to another city by

```
train1.AssignTo(lineInCity1);
train1.AssignTo(null);
train1.AssignTo(lineInCity2);
```

The requirements do not specify whether this should be allowed or not.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at it.

Comment: It works, thank you. the teleportation I guess is handled in the test 4 when assigning a train to a null line removes its assignment()

Comment: New issues occurred when I passed test 3 & 4.
1. Test 1 on line 19 & Test 2  on line 38: "Sequence contains no elements"
2. Test 5 on line 90 : "Expected value to be 2, but found 0"